# ¿Como logro hacer que la ultima impresión no muestre la coma(,)?

Tags: php

Tengo un ciclo while que me muestra los números impares y ademas agrega una coma cada ves que se imprime, la pregunta es ¿Como logro hacer que la ultima impresión no muestre la coma(,)?

Comment: Hola Juan Sebastian Cruz Castillo bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que realices el [tour] para que conozcas como funciona el sitio y así ganas tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Por favor Revisa ¿[ask]? para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: @Juan ¿podrías agregar tu código en la pregunta?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Comment: Yo tengo una sugerencia, pero las normativas de StackOverflow indican que debes poner algo de tu parte y no esperar a que otros hagan el código por ti.

Answer (score 0):

Toma el resultado final en una variable y con la función substr le quitas el último caracter. Por ejemplo:

```
$string = "hola,";
$rest = substr($string, 0, -1);
echo $rest; //imprime 'hola'
```